# Ansatz vs. Herangehensweise

Tags: word-choice

Ich würde gern den Unterschied zwischen den Worten im folgenden Satz wissen.

> Deine Herangehensweise, wie du arbeitest, gefällt mir nicht.

vs

> Dein Ansatz, wie du arbeitest, gefällt mir nicht.

Manchmal habe ich den Eindruck, dass wenn ich *Ansatz* in verschiedenen Kontexten verwende, versteht man mich falsch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide Sätze ergeben aus meiner Sicht nicht viel Sinn, bzw. sind seltsam formuliert. Sowohl *Herangehensweise* und *Ansatz* bestimmen im gegebenen Kontext normalerweise, wie man beginnt, ein Problem zu lösen.

Ein *Ansatz* wäre hier beispielsweise ein möglicher abstrakter Lösungsweg, eine *Herangehensweise* ein konkreter Beginn eines Lösungsablaufs.

Beispiel: Der *Ansatz* zur Lösung des Zauberwürfels wäre, zunächst eine Seite mit einer Farbe zu vervollständigen und dann die anderen. Die *Herangehensweise* wäre, zunächst anhand des mittleren Steins zu prüfen, welche Seite später welche Farbe bekommt und dann ...

Beides passt in den Beispielen meiner Meinung nach nicht zu "wie Du arbeitest". Ich würde beide Sätze formulieren als

> Deine Arbeitsweise gefällt mir nicht
>   Deine Art zu Arbeiten gefällt mir nicht

oder aber (bezogen auf ein konkretes Problem)

> Dein (Lösungs-)Ansatz gefällt mir nicht
>   Deine Herangehensweise gefällt mir nicht

Es gibt in verschiedenen Bereichen durchaus auch verschiedene Methoden, nach denen man arbeiten kann um ein Problem zu lösen, z.B. in der Software-Entwicklung das Wasserfallmodell oder iterative Modelle. Möchte man kritisieren, dass jemand nach einem Modell arbeitet, das einem nicht so gefällt, könnte man beispielsweise auch sagen:

> Die Methode, nach der Du arbeitest gefällt mir nicht

Answer (score 3):

Ansatz klingt für mich nach dem ersten Schritt, der Initialidee oder dem Ansatz*punkt* und nicht nach sehr viel mehr.

Demgegenüber klingt Herangehensweise schon vielmehr nach Planung und Vorgehen. (Vielleicht gehört es zur Herangehensweise, verschiedene Ansätze zu probieren?)

Für die grundsätzliche Herangehensweise beim Arbeiten (also nicht auf eine einzelne, konkrete Aufgabe bezogen) könnte man aber auch die Worte Arbeitsstil oder Arbeitsmethodik verwenden, was den Satz deutlich vereinfachen würde:

> Dein Arbeitsstil gefällt mir nicht.

bzw

> Deine Arbeitsmethodik gefällt mir nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Nun ja, *Ansatz* klingt in dem Beispiel wirklich nicht so gut. Das Wort wird eher bei Fachkontexten verwendet, z. B. in der Mathematik und Physik, wenn man annimmt, daß eine gesuchte Lösung eine bestimmte Form hat - das ist dann der Ansatz, und damit die Lösung näher oder ganz bestimmt.

Der erste Satz in der Frage ist besser, auch wenn man ihn wohl eher selten im realen Leben so hören wird.